# PowerPoint 2003: change font size for on-screen Notes display

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In PowerPoint 2003, one can display the speaker notes below the slide image when in "Normal" view.  Is there any way to change the default "much too small" font used there?  Many presenters I work with find it hard to read, especially on smaller laptop panels.  I can't find any obvious options in the menus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, [found a workaround](http://www.accelerating.org/articles/beyondpresenterview.html).  Click in the Notes pane of the Normal view, and you can use the Zoom control on the Standard toolbar to zoom the speaker notes to whatever size is necessary.  You can't change the font, but you can make the default font big enough to read.  Thanks to John Smart of Accelerating.org for the fine explanation he gives.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways:

1. Click on the box where you write in your notes at the bottom of the powerpoint and go up to VIEW --> ZOOM --> IN/OUT (depending on what you want to do)
2. Click on the box where you write in your notes at the bottom of the powerpoint and press command+(-) for zoom out, and command+(+) to zoom in.